# How to infer a member of a (polymorphic) union in function annotations?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Try Flow Link](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCAxhgJZwB2APACoB8YAvGAN5jb4BcYtYAvmABkYABSowYAD5sOuPDwDktAIyKANGACGPSgFcAtgCM8AJwETpszgrDKATIotgAlOmJUAzhjAGsJcioeIlIKGmU1RhZ2GyVaRwsPSm9ff1Cqex4AsOoIxSjreTi1TR0wFXsAZgtUKD1KdMowKDg4US1GrMbc1XyXMB4ANzgyABM2SzIodsaAOhtmJhY8twBIJM84GDxZ+ABzGcDKWa03flQgA)

I'm trying to nail down a specific member of a union type in a function annotation. But it doesn't work the way I expected:

```
/* @flow */

type Action<T> = { type: T } & (
  | { type: 'T1', a: number }
  | { type: 'T2' }
)

const myAction:  Action<'T1'> = { type: 'T1', a: 123 } // <- ok, passes
const myAction2: Action<'T1'> = { type: 'T2' } // <- ok, fails as expected

function foo(action: Action<'T1'>) : void {
  console.log(action.a) // fails

  if(action.type === 'T1')
    console.log(action.a) // also fails
}
```

I would expect flow to infer `action.a` as the correct member of the union. But even when trying a dynamic type test with an `if`-statement it fails with:

```
12:   console.log(action.a) // fails
                  ^ property `a`. Property cannot be accessed on any member of intersection type
12:   console.log(action.a) // fails
                  ^ intersection
```

Any idea what's going on here or how to approach such annotations?